# jquery animate flickering

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

this is a pretty simple problem, and im not sure if there is one, but i am looking for a solution.

the following jquery code causes a bit of flickering in Firefox:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#reply_h2").offset().top},'slow');
```

I was just wondering if there is any way to stop the flickering?

Comment: If the page contains plenty of graphics (flash in particular) you might see a bit of flickering. This is normal.

Comment: Have you tried to use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` and adjust properly your CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a link to site? Are you reaching the page via an anchor? If you are then browser may be jumping to the anchor, and then jQuery animates you back from the top down to your h2 tag.

If an anchor link is the problem then there isn't a ton you can do. The scroll effect is controlled by the browser. You could switch up to a querystring, gup it and then apply your scroll effect.